# How do I make a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, numpy

So I want to generate a population (N) of individuals with a genome of length (genomelength), where their genome consists of '0s', '1s' and '?s' I use the code below and it works how I need I to work:

```
import random 
import numpy as np

def generate_individual(genomelength):
    individual = ''
    for i in range(genomelength):
        locus = random.random()
        if 0<=locus <0.25:
            i = '0'
        elif 0.25<=locus<0.5:
            i = '1'
        else:
            i = '?'
        individual += i
    return individual

print generate_individual(10)
```

However I now need to write a function that will run this N times to generate a population of such strings, and store them in a list/array.
I thought to generate a list of zeros N long but that doesn't seem to work, and I can't find out how to create a blank array to add to, can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: If you are not using `numpy` (because in this chunk of code you are not), take out the import and your program will run noticeably faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) -

```
lst = [generate_individual(10) for _ in range(N)] #You will need to define N before (or use a constant)
print lst
```

You do not need to create a list of empty strings of length N , you can instead create the list you want on the fly as above.

Comment: Small correction, but in Python if you are not using the var in a loop you should just put a `_` :)

Comment: Its just a convention, not a strict rule :)

Comment: Using list comprehension would be faster than his which uses python for loop, as list comprehension uses `C` for loop. Also, the function with the list comprehension would look like - `def generate_population(N, genomelength): return [generate_individual(genomelength) for _ in range(N)]` , which does what you want in one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension.

For example:

```
import random 

def generate_individual(genome_length):
    individual = ''
    for i in range(genome_length):
        locus = random.random()
        if 0 <= locus < 0.25:
            i = '0'
        elif 0.25 <= locus< 0.5:
            i = '1'
        else:
            i = '?'
        individual += i
    return individual


genomes = [generate_individual(10) for _ in range(10)]
print genomes
```

Also, I removed the numpy import, because you aren't using it in this example code.

Answer (score 0):

my friend told me to do this:

```
def generate_population(N, genomelength):
    x = []
    for i in range(N):
        i = gen_individual(genomelength)
        x.append(i)
```

are there any differences between your solution and his? Thanks btw

Comment: Using list comprehension would be faster than his which uses python for loop, as list comprehension uses C for loop. Also, the function with the list comprehension would look like - `def generate_population(N, genomelength): return [generate_individual(genomelength) for _ in range(N)]` , which does what you want in one line of code.